# Firestore rule if true or false

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In firestore you can have rules like below:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /products/{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if true;
    }
}
```

What is meant by `if true` in this line: `allow read, write: if true;`?

What if it is `if false`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It defines the required condition of whether the permissions apply to the path.

```
match <path> {
  allow <permissions>: if <condition>
}
```

The condition can simply be a `true` if you want permissions to apply without any requirements, or the condition can be result of one or multiple values ​​that evaluate to `true` or `false`.

```
match /chatroom/{roomId} {
  allow read, write: if (
    request.auth != null && 
    roomId in get(/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.chats
  );
}
```

The documentation has better examples that explain it in more detail.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions

Answer (score 7):

It means, that read and write will evaluate to true here. which means that everyone can read and write your database.

if false --> will evaluate to the expression to false. for example:

```
allow read, write : if false
```

this will close your database and no one can modify it