# Firebase Storage Exception: User does not have permission to access this object

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I get the following error when upload image to the firebase storage.

plugins versions:

```
image_picker: ^0.6.7+3
firebase_storage: ^3.1.6
permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
```

Firebase Storage rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

And the full error I get in the debug console:

```
E/StorageException( 9672): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException( 9672): User does not have permission to access this object.
E/StorageException( 9672):  Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
E/StorageException( 9672): The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException( 9672): java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:340)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:309)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:223)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:1106)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$10.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/StorageException( 9672): Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied."  }}
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:455)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:435)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:426)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:280)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:294)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:70)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:62)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:476)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:277)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:218)
E/StorageException( 9672):  ... 5 more
E/StorageException( 9672): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException( 9672): User does not have permission to access this object.
E/StorageException( 9672):  Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
E/StorageException( 9672): The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException( 9672): java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:340)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:309)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:223)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:1106)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$10.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/StorageException( 9672): Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied."  }}
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:455)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:435)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:426)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:280)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:294)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:70)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:62)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:476)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:277)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:218)
E/StorageException( 9672):  ... 5 more
E/StorageException( 9672): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException( 9672): User does not have permission to access this object.
E/StorageException( 9672):  Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
E/StorageException( 9672): The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException( 9672): java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:340)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:309)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:223)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:1106)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$10.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/StorageException( 9672): Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied."  }}
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:455)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:435)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:426)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:280)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:294)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:70)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:62)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:476)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:277)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:218)
E/StorageException( 9672):  ... 5 more
E/StorageException( 9672): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException( 9672): User does not have permission to access this object.
E/StorageException( 9672):  Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
E/StorageException( 9672): The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException( 9672): java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:340)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:309)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:223)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:1106)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$10.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/StorageException( 9672): Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied."  }}
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:455)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:435)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:426)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:280)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:294)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:70)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:62)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:476)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:277)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:218)
E/StorageException( 9672):  ... 5 more
E/StorageException( 9672): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException( 9672): User does not have permission to access this object.
E/StorageException( 9672):  Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
E/StorageException( 9672): {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied."  }}
E/StorageException( 9672): java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied."  }}
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:455)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:435)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:426)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:280)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:294)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:70)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:62)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:74)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
E/StorageException( 9672):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/flutter ( 9672): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(download_error, User does not have permission to access this object., null, null)
E/flutter ( 9672): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter ( 9672): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167:18)
E/flutter ( 9672): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9672): #2      StorageReference.getDownloadURL (package:firebase_storage/src/storage_reference.dart:142:12)
E/flutter ( 9672): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9672): #3      FirebaseStorageService.uploadProductImage (package:farmers_market/src/services/firebase_storage_service.dart:14:12)
E/flutter ( 9672): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9672): #4      ProductBloc.pickImage (package:farmers_market/src/blocs/product_bloc.dart:95:24)
E/flutter ( 9672): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9672):
```

and a piece of code

```
PickedFile image;
await Permission.photos.request();
var permissionStatus = await Permission.photos.status;
if (permissionStatus.isGranted) {

    image = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image != null) {
       var imageUrl = await storageService.uploadProductImage(
       File(image.path), uuid.v4());
       changeImageUrl(imageUrl)
    } else {
       print('No Path Received');
    }
} else {
    print('Grant Permissions and try again');
}
```

I succesfully authentificated the firebase service before that. I use Android and emulator to make it. What did I miss?

Comment: As Kantine answered below, your security rules reject all access, to that error is the expected result. You'll want to open up your rules to allow exactly what your code does. For a good primer on security rules, have a look at this section of the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your Firebase rules,

```
allow read, write: if false;
```

means that it is not possible to read or write on your DB. You can change it to `if true` to test if this is the cause of your problem, and then use more accurate rules.

See [Firestore rule if true or false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64043033/firestore-rule-if-true-or-false)